# ¿Cómo puedo saber específicament que sentencia or de la clausula where ha fallado en una consulta de sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Muy buenas, tengo una sentencia sql que contiene en la clausula where cuatro condiciones or. Cómo podría saber cual de ellos ha "fallado" sin necesidad de hacer tres/cuatro consultas? Creo que sería select case y return pero no lo he utilizado nunca. Adjunto consulta, gracias de antemano:

```
SELECT IdSeleccion, Fecha_alta, Id_usuario, IdTipo_Cuadrantes, Fecha_inicio, Fecha_fin FROM dbo.Seleccion_Cuadrantes 
    WHERE 
    Fecha_inicio >= '".$Fecha_Entrada_Vigor."' AND Fecha_fin is null AND IdTipo_Cuadrantes=".$IdTipo_Cuadrantes." and Id_usuario=".$Id_usuario."
    OR
    Fecha_inicio <= '".$Fecha_Entrada_Vigor."' AND Fecha_fin is null AND IdTipo_Cuadrantes=".$IdTipo_Cuadrantes." and Id_usuario=".$Id_usuario."
    OR
    Fecha_inicio < '".$Fecha_Entrada_Vigor."' AND Fecha_fin is null AND IdTipo_Cuadrantes=".$IdTipo_Cuadrantes." and Id_usuario=".$Id_usuario."
    OR
    Fecha_inicio >= '".$Fecha_Entrada_Vigor."' and Id_usuario=".$Id_usuario."";
```

Comment: Hola Markus, para crear 4 condiciones con `OR` necesitas agruparlas utilizando paréntesis, por ejemplo, `WHERE (a AND b) OR (c AND d)`

Comment: Hola, muy buenas. Hasta ahí correcto pero como se cual ha fallado ??? La sentencia me tendría que poder retornar un valor cuando falla cada una de ellas. ¿Cómo podría hacer eso sin tener que hacer cuatro consultas individuales con la perdida de optimización que eso supone ?

Comment: Así como podes retornar datos (_columnas_) de una tabla, podes retornar datos calculados. ¿Te gustaria obtener en 1 solo dato cual de las 4 condiciones fallo o en 4, un por cada condición?. Dicho sea de paso ¿que versión de SQL Server utilizas? y no dejes de realizar el [tour]

Comment: La versión és 15.0.2000.5. Necesitaría obtener los 4 datos.

Comment: Esto no parece SQL Server. O tal vez es código desde el back-end y se está abriendo la puerta a inyección de SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Pues básicamente tienes que probar cada condición a nivel del `select` y no al nivel del `where`:

```
SELECT  IdSeleccion, 
    Fecha_alta, 
    Id_usuario, 
    IdTipo_Cuadrantes, 
    Fecha_inicio, 
    Fecha_fin,
    CASE WHEN NOT (Fecha_inicio >= '".$Fecha_Entrada_Vigor."' AND Fecha_fin is null AND IdTipo_Cuadrantes=".$IdTipo_Cuadrantes." and Id_usuario=".$Id_usuario.") THEN 'Si' ELSE '' END  AS 'FalloOr1',
    CASE WHEN NOT (Fecha_inicio <= '".$Fecha_Entrada_Vigor."' AND Fecha_fin is null AND IdTipo_Cuadrantes=".$IdTipo_Cuadrantes." and Id_usuario=".$Id_usuario.") THEN 'Si' ELSE '' END  AS 'FalloOr2',
    CASE WHEN NOT (Fecha_inicio < '".$Fecha_Entrada_Vigor."' AND Fecha_fin is null AND IdTipo_Cuadrantes=".$IdTipo_Cuadrantes." and Id_usuario=".$Id_usuario.") THEN 'Si' ELSE '' END  AS 'FalloOr3',
    CASE WHEN NOT (Fecha_inicio >= '".$Fecha_Entrada_Vigor."' and Id_usuario=".$Id_usuario."") THEN 'Si' ELSE '' END  AS 'FalloOr4'
    FROM dbo.Seleccion_Cuadrantes
```

Notas: Esto replicando las condiciones originales del where de tu pregunta, pero revisa la sintaxis por que no me parece que estuviera bien. Obviamente no hay `where` por que no queremos filtrar sino saber que filas eventualmente fallaran la condición

Comment: Yo estaba esperando que el OP me diga la versión para saber si podía usar `IIF`  xD

Comment: @Marcos, agrega la versión con `IIF()` de hecho seguramente es más clara.